# Speed Issues With FileSize Function

Tags: delphi

Ok,

I Use this Function to get filesize in my program and it works pretty well even for files above 4GB.

```
function FileSize(const PathtoFile: string): Int64;
var
  AttributeData: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(PathtoFile), GetFileExInfoStandard,
    @AttributeData) then
  begin
    Int64Rec(Result).Lo := AttributeData.nFileSizeLow;
    Int64Rec(Result).Hi := AttributeData.nFileSizeHigh;
  end
  else
    Result := -1;
end;
```

Now, The Problem is that when profiling my app with AQTime Standard, I Discovered that my program spends about `35 Secs` in this function when getting the filesize of about `4758 Files` in contrast to the time my `GetFileAttribute Function Spends which is about 5 Secs` when processing the same number of files.
Please is there any Code I can use in place of my current one (even if it is ASM) to speed up the operation.

Comment: Are the files all in the same directory? If so, Windows itself starts having issues with that large number (4K) of files in a single directory. Are the files located on a network drive? You could also be running into network latency issues. I tested your code against FindFirstFileEx, and returning the size of a single file on a network drive took exactly the same time (3ms) for both functions; testing using a local file took 0ms for both based on TStopWatch timings.

Comment: The Files in the directory are of varying sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Both GetFileAttributesEx and GetFileAttributes are windows api calls. There's really not much gain there.

One of the things you can consider is reading the MFT directly, which if you get it to work will be blazingly fast. It's not an easy 5 line solution though.

See this answer for a bit more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3061745/1107597

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. will look into it.
still waiting for some other suggestions though :).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get file size by using FindFist and then reading Size filed from TSearchRec that is returned by this function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i would love to stay away from FindFirst Stuff.

Comment: @Xor-el, have you even tried to compare speed with "FindFirst Stuff" vs. `GetFileAttributesEx`

Comment: @kobik, I will do that but am currently away from my development PC.

Comment: @Xor Do you want your program to go faster or not? Try FindFirstFile and see if it is faster.

Comment: I Will do that when am on my development PC. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Isn't the FindFirst stuff essentially deprecated, or at least superceded?

Comment: @alcalde Not at all. It is the way to enumerate files. But it doesn't always get the file size right. Usually that doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
function getFileSize( vFileName : String ) : Int64;
var F : TFileStream;
begin
  Result := 0; // or -1

  try

    if FileExists( vFileName ) then
    try
      F := TFileStream.Create( vFileName );
      Result := F.Size;
    finally
      F.Free;
    end;

  except end;

end;
```

or like [Kobik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937125/kobik) and  [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) said:

```
function getFileSizeInteger( vFileName : String ) : Integer;
var SR : TSearchRec;
begin
  Result := 0; // or -1

  if FindFirst( vFileName, faArchive, SR ) then
  try
    Result := SR.Size;
  finally
    FindClose( SR );
  end;

end;
```

The problem in second option (with FindFirst) is that Result is limited to Integer bounds (4GB).

The first option is good enought for me in all ways.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the first function has to create a stream which incurs some overhead which is pretty higher than my first function.
will try kobik and david method and report back.

Comment: -1. The first option is not acceptable at all. Not only does it have to open the file and do a Seek to find the size, but it will fail if the file couldn't be opened, and can cause other code/applications to fail because it interferes with their ability to open the file. FindFirst is not an alternative, because the poster has mentioned that there are times the file is greater than 4GB in size. IOW, neither of the solutions you've presented are workable answers to the question.

Comment: Why can't you return an Int64?

Comment: Ken White: I just try to help... and I said that second option has size issues, just figuring out the comments above. I have checked sizes of about 5k files in just 10 seconds with first option... no too bad to lost my reputation. let the user accept or not the answer!

Comment: Sertac Akyuz: because SR.Size returns Integer!

Comment: I checked the versions I have. D7 has an integer, D2007 has an Int64. As there's no version tag in the question, you can use an Int64. (Link to documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TSearchRec ).

Comment: The poster can feel free to accept your answer if they want; it does not change the fact that the answer is wrong, and I've already explained why. The purpose of voting here (up or down) is to judge the quality of the answer, and IMO neither of your alternatives is a good solution. (Actually, the TFileStream solution is worse than I stated; reading `Size` actually causes 3 separate Seek calls: 1 to save the current position, one to move to the end to get the Size, and then a third to return to the original position.)

Comment: In addition, the poster said the code shown takes 5 seconds to process 4.7K files; you say the filestream takes 10 seconds to process 5K, which means it takes two times longer to do the same amount of work. How is that an *improvement*?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Even in the older versions that use Integer for `TSearchRec.Size`, you can get a full Int64 value by using `TSearchRec.FindData.nFileSize(Low/High)` instead of `TSearchRec.Size`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Yup, and always has been.